# Need Help in fetching result of Gremlin query into Python data structures

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I am trying to run a Gremlin query on AWS Neptune database from inside Python code and want to store the returned data into Python List. This is working fine for simple Gremlin queries but some more complex ones seem to be having an issue.

Below is the code, The first Gremlin query is working fine but not the second one. The Node does not exist so this can be tried without importing any data.

```
from __future__  import print_function  # Python 2/3 compatibility

from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

graph = Graph()

remoteConn = DriverRemoteConnection('wss://sdm-neptune-db-instance-1.cduuicw2rgrv.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/gremlin','g')
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(remoteConn)

cust_List=g.V('AZ50K115E39AX').hasLabel('tp21tpcust').count().toList()
for p in cust_List:
    print('Data Fetched: ' + str(p))

cust_List=g.V('XXXXXXXX').hasLabel('tp21tpcust').local(__.repeat(__.out().simplePath()).until(__.not_(__.out())).path().by(id).limit(100)).local(__.unfold().union(__.limit(1),__.tail()).fold()).dedup().toList()
for p in cust_List:
    print('Data Fetched' + p)

remoteConn.close()
```

Here is the error, any guidance will be appreciated

```
Data Fetched: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestPythonGremlin.py", line 19, in <module>
    cust_List=g.V('XXXXXXXX').hasLabel('tp21tpcust').local(__.repeat(__.out().simplePath()).until(__.not_(__.out())).path().by(id).limit(100)).local(__.unfold().union(__.limit(1),__.tail()).fold()).dedup().toList()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 58, in toList
    return list(iter(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 48, in __next__
    self.traversal_strategies.apply_strategies(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 573, in apply_strategies
    traversal_strategy.apply(traversal)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/remote_connection.py", line 149, in apply
    remote_traversal = self.remote_connection.submit(traversal.bytecode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/driver_remote_connection.py", line 55, in submit
    result_set = self._client.submit(bytecode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/client.py", line 127, in submit
    return self.submitAsync(message, bindings=bindings).result()
  File "/opt/Python-3.7.9/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 428, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/opt/Python-3.7.9/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py", line 66, in cb
    f.result()
  File "/opt/Python-3.7.9/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 428, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/opt/Python-3.7.9/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/opt/Python-3.7.9/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py", line 74, in write
    request_id, request_message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/serializer.py", line 144, in serialize_message
    message = self.build_message(request_id, processor, op, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/serializer.py", line 154, in build_message
    return self.finalize_message(message, b"\x21", self.version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/serializer.py", line 157, in finalize_message
    message = json.dumps(message)
  File "/opt/Python-3.7.9/Lib/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/opt/Python-3.7.9/Lib/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/opt/Python-3.7.9/Lib/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/opt/Python-3.7.9/Lib/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type builtin_function_or_method is not JSON serializable
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clue is in the error message. In Python `id` is a built in function. Try `T.id` instead.

`T` is a special class/enum that can be used when you need to refer to `T.id` or `T.label`. It is part of the Apache TinkerPop Gremlin Python client (and also available in general as part of TinkerPop).

You will just need to include the file containing the definition into your code.

`from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T`

Comment: Hi Kelvin, Thank you for your response and this may sound a bit dumb; what is T referring to ? are you suggesting using T as an alias for Nodes and then use T.id ? Just getting started to explore Graph Databases so pardon my ignorance

Comment: Somehow I missed this comment. T refers to a TinkerPop class/enum that is used when referring to labels and IDs.